# Distributing React UI Library with styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a junior developer who just started working in a company.

I have a bit of experience in React and could not solve the current situation.

The situation i am having a trouble with is that when I import from the library that I have distributed in npm, my React project cannot recognize the styled components.

I get this error on my project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFQQu.png)

I have researched and realized that the babel needs more options such as using 
"babel-plugin-styled-components" option.

Unfortunately, this did not work after using the command and distributed with the commands

yarn build   == webpack --mode production

Is there anyway that I can use styled-components library??

thank you!

P:S: I think I need to put more information.

Many people thankfully answered my question but I tried them and I got an another error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfP8p.png)

P.S: 
My file structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JiZW.png)

My code of Button

```
export const StyledButton = styled.button`
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  color: palevioletred;
  margin: 0.5em 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
      ${props => props.primary && css`
        background: palevioletred;
        color: white;
      `}
    `;
export default class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   console.log("Props:", props);
}
render() {
  return (
  <div>
    <StyledButton>{this.props.children}</StyledButton>
    {/* <button> {this.props.children} </button> */}
  </div>);
}
```

}

My index.js of Button

```
import Button from "./Button";
```

export default Button;

```
My index.js of src folder

export * from "./components";
```

My babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function BabelConfigJS(api) {
api.cache(true);

const presets = ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"];

const plugins = [
    "styled-components",
    [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        {
            corejs: 2,
            helpers: true,
            regenerator: true,
            useESModules: false,
        },
    ],
    [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        {
            loose: true,
        },
    ], 
];

return {
    sourceType: "unambiguous",
    presets,
    plugins,
};
};
```

PS: Error code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dg1T.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faVdo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq7Ku.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you post the actual error you're receiving, as well as the code for the component? All the image is showing is that you have an error in the component, which doesn't help us when trying to help you.

Comment: Sure! I will post it.

Comment: Can you post the error text as well?

Comment: Sure! I will post it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error (which really is just an Eslint complaint) does not refer to using `styled-components` at all!

It's just saying components should be in PascalCase, not camelCase as you have now.

That is, instead of `<styledComponent />`, it'd be `<StyledComponent />`.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. However, I got another error after I changed that I mentioned on the post. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the component name to be Uppercased, it has nothing to do with babel, etc.

```
// not <styledButton/>
<StyledButton/>
```

It is a requirement from React as in JSX lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question! However, I got an another error that I added at the end of my post.